# How to validate an angularjs in textbox?

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-pattern

Why is my ng-pattern in textbox of name is allowing special characters?
This is the view file:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in config.students">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="students[]" ng-trim="false" ng-model="class.students[$index]" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="removeStudent($index)" type="button">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-grad btn-rect">Submit</button>
        <a href ="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/main/index" class="btn btn-default btn-grad btn-rect">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of angularJS you are using?

Comment: My angularJS version is 1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

`ng-pattern` alone will not prevent a user from entering certain text into a textbox. If you want to do that, you'll need to use a custom attribute directive on the `<input>`.

`ng-pattern` is meant to be used in conjunction with AngularJS' form validation, you can use it to hide/show validation messages and to validate a form before it is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS form validations requires unique name for each input field in the form.

But in your case you are using the same name for all the input fields in ng-repeat.
So change your input to add unique name for input in each iteration using $index

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="students{{$index}}" ng-trim="false" ng-model="class.students[$index]" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/">
```

Here is the <kbd>[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OaoTuM?p=preview)</kbd>.